# How to remove my own instagram followers with Python?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, instagram

I want to remove my own instagram followers without blocking them, using python.

I have seen [many](https://pypi.org/project/instapy/), [many](https://instaloader.github.io/), [many](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api), [many](https://pypi.org/project/InstagramAPI/) instagram python libraries online that allow you to stop or start following a person, but that is not what I'm looking for; I don't want to remove who I am following or start following someone, I want to remove people who are following me.

I looked into [the official documentation of Instagram's HTTP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) trying to make my own solution, but I couldn't find the documentation of this action under any endpoint ( I assume it should be under `/friends/` ).

I vaguely remember some library that used to do this, but I cannot find it. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this, preferably via passing an inclusion/exclusion list for the followers I want to have as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in [an old library](https://github.com/canpoyrazoglu/instagram-ghost-remover) that does something similar. You can't directly remove followers through most tools, but if you block and then unblock a user, the effect you want is achieved. Example code:

```
# https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/instagram_private_api/endpoints/friendships.html
import instagramPrivateApi
# ...
# Implement a Client class that inherits FriendshipMixin
api = new Client()
api.friendships_block(uid)
api.friendships_unblock(uid)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the API endPoint for removing a follower** `https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/{user_id}/remove_follower/`

You can do a post request on this URL with appropriate headers and that can do the job.

Comment: I tried this web api but it is not working.